# Term for a former prisoner, who seems to have an aura of jail hanging around him

Tags: single-word-requests

I read in a book about this effect, and I just can't remember the term for it. It describes the effect with a name, something like: "shadow of jail about him" or something. This is seriously driving me crazy. I've tried and tried to remembered, and googled, and I still can't remember it.

It describes people who have got out of jail, and they seem to have the aura of jail still around them. I know it is actually a phrase, not something the author coined. Can someone please help me? And sorry for the vague kind of guidelines.

If you want to know, that book was something I read years ago when I was younger, called

*Jo's Boys*

Comment: do you remember if the term was immediately obvious, obvious from context or you had to look it up?

Comment: _[Jo's Boys](http://books.google.com/books?id=mEsPakNJWZYC&pg=PA15&dq=%22coitarche%22+%2Bfirst&hl=en&ei=FvfuTf3QBIncgQeWrJ2VDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&sqi=2&ved=0CGEQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22coitarche%22%20%2Bfirst&f=false)_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few metaphors that occur in *Jo's Boys* that resemble what you're talking about.

pp. 263: "They'd see and smell and feel the prison taint on me..."

pp. 327: "He longed to go home, but waited week after week to get the prison taint off him and the haggard look out of his face."

pp. 338: "All the old prison gloom seemed to settle like a black cloud on Dan's face..."

pp. 343: "... and to help wear away the first sharpness of the prison brand."

Comment: Ah!  **Taint**! - but it often has [a different connotation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/perineum)...

Answer (score 8):

A person who has done time is often called a "**[jailbird](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/jailbird)**", an "**[ex-con](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/ex-con)**", an "**[old lag](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/old-lag)**"...

Comment: The feeling I get from "jailbird" is someone who keeps returning to the "cage" (to continue that metaphore).  The feeling I get from "ex-con" is that it wasn't necessarily a recent departure.  I've never heard the term "old lag" before.

Comment: I know what they're called, I'm just wondering why they have that sort of *atmosphere* around them.

Comment: @Ham - perhaps you should re-title your question, then, because I believe I _did_ answer "Term for a person who got out of jail, and an aura of jail seems to hang around him".  No, I haven't answered what that "aura of jail" is called - I'm drawing a blank on that - but the question in your title...

Comment: Also, I did a quick re-read through _Jo's Boys_ - I also read it as a kid, and it's [available through Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/3499/3499-h/3499-h.htm) - but the phrase you remember didn't come from there, I think.